# How do I implement a search function in Binary Search Tree using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

The function searchNode doesn't work correct. When searching an element which is in binary tree it returns None instead of True. I don't understand why it is None, because it should return either True or False but never None. Can you tip me how to fix it?

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

class BinarySearchTree:
def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.visited = 0

def insert(self,value):
    if self.root is None:
        self.root =  Node(value)
    else:
        self.insertNode(self.root, value)

def insertNode(self,current, value):
    if value <= current.value:
        if  current.left:
            self.insertNode(current.left, value)
        else:
            current.left = Node(value)
    else:
        if current.right:
            self.insertNode(current.right, value)
        else:
            current.right = Node(value)

def fromArray(self, newarr):
    for each in newarr:
        self.insert(each)
    return

def search(self, value):
    self.visited = 0
    self.searchNode(self.root, value)

def searchNode(self,current,value):
    if (current is None):
        return False
    elif (value == current.value):
        return True
    elif (value < current.value):
        self.visited += 1
        return self.searchNode(current.left, value)
    else:
        self.visited += 1
        return self.searchNode(current.right, value)
```

Comment: How are you calling this method and evaluating the result?

Comment: Paste your code instead of screenshots.

Comment: Please copy paste your code (taking care of indentation) in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You never return anything in `search`. You probably want to `return self.searchNode(self.root, value)` instead of just calling it.

Comment: Thank you! It is working correctly now. I added return in search function